# How to add a Bubble Notification to a WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I programmed a WordPress plugin for a newsletter subscription, but the problem that I’m facing is the bubble notification. I tried to lookup for an article, but all the articles I found are 100 lines for the bubble notification and I don't like copy paste. I want to understand it so I can use it in my next plugins.

The idea is: when 10 people subscribe to the newsletter, the bubble notifications shows up (10).

```
$new = $wpdb->query("select * from subscribers");
if($new !=0)
{
    echo put how many new subscriber in the news letter ($new);
}
```

How to add that to the menu of my plugin?

Comment: Please rephrase your question, I haven't got a clue what you are asking

Answer (score 2):

If you had [researched for "bubble"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=bubble) at WordPress Answers, you'd have found, if not a solution, very good hints.

From [this Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3942/12615), an adapted example to add `10` to Advanced Custom Field plugin menu. Check the code comments:

```
add_filter( 'add_menu_classes', 'add_plugin_bubble_so_17525062');

function add_plugin_bubble_so_17525062( $menu ) 
{
    $pending_count = 10; // Use your code to create this number

    foreach( $menu as $menu_key => $menu_data ) 
    {
        // From the plugin URL http://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=acf
        if( 'edit.php?post_type=acf' != $menu_data[2] )
            continue;
        $menu[$menu_key][0] .= " <span class='update-plugins count-$pending_count'><span class='plugin-count'>" . number_format_i18n($pending_count) . '</span></span>';
    }
    return $menu;
}
```

Comment: It's an example on how to add the bubble to any plugin. In this case, ACF. Adapt to suit your needs, or show the code you're working with.